# Does a magnetic field induce an emf in a loop of wire

Tags: electromagnetism

Is it true that any magnetic field induces an emf in a loop of wire? If It it is true then kindly explain me with an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ask:

> Is it true that any magnetic field induces an emf in a loop of wire?

No, not in  any setup. Only if there is a **change** in the magnetic lines passing through a loop. It is how [electric generators work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_generators).

[Here is a simple example](http://www.physics.sjsu.edu/becker/physics51/induction.htm) of a loop in a changing magnetic field.